# Why do we need to memset always with zero?

Tags: c++, c

Whenever we use `memset` we set it with zero.

Why? Why not with 1 or 2 or something else.

Also, setting a struct to 0  seems to work but setting to 1 doesn't:

```
typedef struct abc{
    int a;
} abc;

int main()
{
    abc* ab;
    memset(ab, 0, sizeof(abc));// it sets abc->a = 0; correct
}
```

But instead of `0` if I use `1` like:

```
memset(ab, 1, sizeof(abc));
```

then the value of `abc->a = garbage` or `not equals to 1`

Why?

Comment: Because `memset` sets all the **bytes** to the specified value, not the integer as a whole.

Comment: Your program never allocates the destination of pointer `ab`. The program is undefined behavior (but this does not have to be the reason why `ab->a` is not one).

Comment: because 0 is initial value.

Comment: @sgar91: Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Pick a language. then either allocate data for your pointer to address or declare a variable of proper type (`abc`) and use that address. As written `abc* ab;` declares a pointer with an indeterminate value (means you have no idea what it is). Using this as the target for writing in a `memset()` call is undefined behavior. Also, your `main()` program implies an `int` return value if it is C, and fails to compile if it is standard C++. Declare it as `int main()` and return a value (EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE).

Comment: For C++ The answer is pretty simple: Don't use `memset`. Use `std::fill` (or `std::fill_n`) instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't always need to `memset` to 0, this is just the most common (and useful) thing to do.

`memset` sets each **byte** to some given value. An `int` consists of 4 bytes, so, when `memset`ing to `1`, you'd set each of those 4 to `1`, then you'd have `00000001 | 00000001 | 00000001 | 00000001`<sub>2</sub> = `16843009`<sub>10</sub> (the first numbers are in binary, the last in decimal).

Also - note that you're never allocating memory for `ab`. Even though your code may work now, it's not safe. This would be:

```
abc ab;
memset(&ab, 0, sizeof(abc));
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, `0` is largely arbitrary. However, if we had to pick reasons, it's for convenience (at the cost of safety - you should prefer to explicitly initialise variables if you ever depend on them):

- 0 is mostly understood as an initial value for integers, signed or unsigned, as it represents 0 no matter the width or endianness
- 0 is an end-of-string for `char*`s
- 0 is often 0.0 for floating point numbers
- 0 is often `NULL` in C, guaranteed to be `NULL` in C++

Comment: How is 0 guaranteed to set a floating point variable to 0.0? What part of the language standard guarantees that?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: There are other standards besides the language standard, and some of them are more ubiquitous.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley So, you agree that the language standard does not guarantee that 0.0 is represented with all zero bits?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I don't know if it does or not. But I do believe it is a real guarantee(even if not specified by the language standard) that is stronger than some things that *are* in fact specified by the language standard.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It does not make such a guarantee. It only describes conformant models but not their bit representations.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Okay.  Either way, it doesn't matter.  Like I said, there are other standards.  And those standards are followed more universally than the C or the C++ language standards.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know POSIX is more strict than the C (C++) standard in a few places, so if you rely on those stricter things as in POSIX, your C code suddenly becomes less portable. Does it not matter? It depends.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I'm talking about floating point standards.  I argue that no, your code does not become less portable if you rely on the binary representation of 0 in floating point numbers, because there are only a few floating point systems in use (in environments that more than 1 person uses), and they all represent 0.0 the same way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is fine, but that is not a universal guarantee. And that's the whole point.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is a novel meaning of the word universal.

Comment: In C++, while the literal zero will get converted to nullptr when assigned to a pointer type, the actual bits of nullptr may not be all zeros. Since memset does not know whether the memory it is setting is for storing a pointer or not, it doesn't know to do such a conversion. So memset to zero on memory that is meant to store a pointer isn't guaranteed to set the pointer to nullptr. (Whether you'll actually ever use a system where nullptr isn't all zero bits, however, is another issue.)

Answer (score 2):

The value you use with `memset()` to set memory to depends on your needs. That's all. No one keeps you from using any other value to initialise memory.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your program When variable is defined, by default it will point to any location and any junk data can be previously available there.

we generally memset to (0)zero to make sure that variable is initialized to zero, so that later on in the program we can trust that the value assigned to the variable is genuinely assigned value and not any garbage.

hope it helps.....

Comment: Why only with `0`? Why not with any other value?

Comment: Cuz "0" is the most common value to set anything. Now suppose, you set the values to "3". Now the same struct is read by any other application written by some other guy. Now he will think that ab->a = 3 is a valid value and will use it for further processing of data. But if you will send ab->a = 0, he will know that your struct is not carrying any valid data and will stop the execution at that point.

Comment: because we all know that zero represent nothing(empty). Thats why.
You can try with 1,2 up to 255 any value also in case you want to use it for comparison. but you should know that memset applies to all bytes. 
For example in your case the struct has int as member and assuming int as 4 bytes it will assign 1 to all 4 bytes so when you print the value you will not get 1 but decimal 4369 or 0x1111. So be careful.

Comment: Now again, suppose you have another member in your struct "char b[20]". Now you gave some random value to it like ab->b = "nayak" ( mind that you forgot to put a "\0" <NULL> char at end. Now when reading your "ab->b" as string, I will never encounter NULL and hence would try to read past the buffer or worst any undefined consequence can happen. In this case, memset'ing your struct to 0 will come very handy as the next byte after "Nayak" will be "0". So even when you make a blunder like forgetting NULL, your code would not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your program got an undefined behavior the reaosn is memory for abc* ab; is never allocated!

Secondly it is required that string should be terminated with "null", which mean it is the end, so inspired by this we use null in memset. But you can use any value you want...

Comment: Talking about `zero` instead of `null` would be less ambigious.